# Error in TikZ using defined \coordinates with \draw to [in= , out=] syntax

Tags: tikz-pgf

Dear fellow LaTeX/TikZ users. I'm clearly misunderstanding something about how TikZ handles coordinate definitions. I am trying to draw a Bezier curve between prededfined points, but TikZ complains as soon as the target point is a defined coordinate (here `(B)`) instead of a literal coordinate (here `(10,10)`) the compile fails with the following error:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `up' (in 'up').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.16   \draw (A) to [out=down,in=up] (B)
;
?
```

I tried to google this but can't seem to find this specific error. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
% EDIT: This is for workaround
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,1);
  \coordinate (B) at (10,10);

  % This will work
  \draw (0,1) to [out=down,in=up] (10,10);
  % So will this
  \draw (A)   to [out=down,in=up] (10,10);  
  % And this
  \draw (A) -- (B);

  % But these wont
  % \draw (A) to [out=down,in=up] (B);
  % \draw (0,1) to [out=down,in=up] (B);

  % EDIT: Added the following workaround:
  \draw ($(A)$) to [out=down,in=up] ($(B)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

I found a workaround, but it made me even more confused. Using `\tikzlibrary{calc}` and replacing `(B)` with `($(B)$)` removes the problem, but I don't understand why. The `($...$)` enviroment for `calc` allows calculations for points, but how/why is `($(B)$)` different from `(B)`?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that if you use a named coordinate (or a node) as target, tikz will use the `in` value as anchor. But there is no `up` anchor in a node. This means that `in=90` (which will set a target `B.90`) or `in=north` (which will set a target `B.north`) will work, but not `in=up` as `B.up` doesn't exist.

Your work-around works as in this case the target is converted in an absolute coordinate (0.0pt,28.45274pt) and tikz doesn't try to use the `in` value as anchor.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,1);
  \coordinate (B) at (10,10);

  \draw (A) to [out=down,in=90] (B);
  \draw (A) to [out=down,in=north] (B);
  %won't work 
 % \draw (A) to [out=down,in=up] (B);

  \draw (A) to [out=down,in=up] ($(B)$);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! My general level confusion has turned into specific knowledge that I do not understand how anchors work or, to be honest, what anchors even are. The latter is much more actionable :)

Comment: Look in the documentation at chapter Shape Library. There you can see the various anchors. A coordinate is a bit special but things like "B.south" works there too.